is there any common way to debug this kind of error?
Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response::setContent(): Argument #1 ($content) must be of type ?string, App\Http\Helpers\PaymentGateway given, called in D:\xamp_8.2\htdocs\salonhub_project\salonhub_1\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Http\Response.php on line 72
Help me to debug above laravel error or this kind of error

seems somewhere a method you are calling expects a string, but you are passing an object instance. follow the stack trace to for more details

App\Http\Helpers\PaymentGateway  $content param

"is there any common way to debug this kind of error?" - yes, any debugger (my favorite is XDebug) is able to help you out. Also, why not check the stacktrace?

need to see full code first
